# No results for query of Soundcloud API under iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, soundcloud

When using the SC.get() function of the Soundcloud API instead of a result I receive a "HTTP Error: 0". The same codes is working under Android and in the browser (with same origin policy disabled).

This is the part of the code:

```
SC.initialize({client_id : "[myclientID]" ,redirect_uri:"[myURI]"});

SC.get('/resolve', {url : '[myURL]'}, function(track, error) {
    if (error)  alert('Error: ' + error.message);
    trackImg[l] =  track.artwork_url;
    trackID[l] = track.id;
    ...
});
```

The URLs are white-listed as external hosts within the projects .plist and the Cordova.plist (the project is still running under phonegap 1.7.0). There is no warning in the Xcode console about blocked URLs..

Strangely enough the app was working fine a couple of weeks ago. The only thing I found changed was that the callback.html for the redirect URI got deleted but I created a new one.